# Creating a user's own folder on user registration

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I need a plugin or some guidence on creating a user's own folder on user registation.

For example...A user clicks on Register and registers ... I need wordpress to create a directory which would be linked with this user.

The reason I want to do this is because I am going to work on building a dashboard where a wordpress template will display the contents of this user's own directory.

Let me explain further step by step: (Note: "Not Req" means I don't need help with this step)

1. User Registers and wordpress creates a directory called the same as the username.
2. User uploads images to that specific directory via ftp or upload - **"Not Req"**
3. I create a template that would display the content of the directory / sub (images) in some kind of tree format.

Right now, what I need to do is step 1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean an upload directory? Besides that WordPress works with virtual paths only, there are no dedicated directories for anything.

Comment: Give us more on your intent & we will suggest you a good implementation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `user_register` action to hook into the register proces and then create the user directory with `wp_mkdir_p`.

```
function create_user_dir($user_id) {
    $user_info = get_userdata( $user_id );

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $user_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/user_dirs/' . $user_info->user_login;

    wp_mkdir_p($user_dir);
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'create_user_dir');
```

This example makes a directory in `uploads/user_dirs`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mkdir_p