# How to create a dedicated folder for specific role via registration

Tags: urls, user-roles, user-registration

I need to include an option in registration page so that user can enter a name for the folder that we can create for them (like this:  http://MyDomain.com/User_named_folder or page).
I saw this in Buddypress which it shows in its registration page where user can name their own Blogs page and administer it. 
Any help or direction would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51065/creating-a-users-own-folder-on-user-registration

Comment: I found that as well but since I'm a newbie, I couldn't figure our where I need to apply this modification.  I tried asking a question on that thread but I got a negative point.